# Spring Security filterChainProxy ?!?! Declare all the filter to use only one custom filter?

Tags: spring, security

I am not sure about filterChainProxy, I have spring security working fine in my application, but I need to load the ConfigAttributes from properties file..

I know I need de create class implementing FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.. then I made it.. after that

When I was reading about this.. I saw in the documentation I have to declare filterchaeinProxy on application context xml.. like this..

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
  <constructor-arg>
    <list>
       <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="
           securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCTrue,
           formLoginFilter,
           exceptionTranslationFilter,
           filterSecurityInterceptor" />
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Do I really need to declare all these filters to use only one custom filter ?

I want just pull my urls and the respective role from properties file..

Comment: Edited my answer below to provide a real solution, even if it's just a hack... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the documentation section ["Adding in Your Own Filters"](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-filters):

> Note that you can't replace filters which are created by the use of the `<http>` element itself - `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`, `ExceptionTranslationFilter` or `FilterSecurityInterceptor`.

That is why you have to define the whole chain yourself if you want to customize one of these three filters.

---

Probably it's too late for you, but just as a follow-up on this question: you could apply the following not-so-beautiful hack to customize the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` created by the namespace configuration in order to avoid having to create the whole filter chain manually.

Create a class that does nothing except setting your `CustomSecurityMetadataSource` on the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` which it receives in its constructor.

```
public class FilterSecurityInterceptorInitializer {
    @Autowired
    public FilterSecurityInterceptorInitializer(
            FilterSecurityInterceptor filterSecurityInterceptor,
            CustomSecurityMetadataSource securityMetadataSource) {
        filterSecurityInterceptor
            .setSecurityMetadataSource(securityMetadataSource);
    }
}
```

Then include this initializer class in your context:

```
<bean class="FilterSecurityInterceptorInitializer" autowire="constructor"/>
<bean class="CustomSecurityMetadataSource"/>
```